# If $a_n$ doesn't have any subsequence that converges, can $|a_n|$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

If a sequence $a_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ doesn't have any convergent subsequence can $|a_n|\rightarrow a$, $a\in[0,\infty)$?

My intuition says that this isn't possible but I'm not sure how to prove it..

Comment: Well, if the absolute sequence converges then so does the sequence of positive terms and the sequence of negative terms (one of which, at least, must be infinite).

Comment: Hint: do you know any conditions which imply that $a_n$ _does_ have a convergent subsequence? Your sequence must violate those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If $(|a_n|) $ is convergent, then $(a_n) $ is bounded. Now invoke Bolzano-Weierstraß. Conclusion?

Comment: Is there any specific theorem that suggests so?